# Firebase image-magick convert not working

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, imagemagick

I am trying to write some text over a gif and then convert it into base 64. But I am getting some error which I am not able to resolve. I found some examples on internet but all of them are using local temp files not URI based.

Here is what I am doing in my functions:

```
var spawnPromise = spawn(
      'convert',
      [
        `"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/blizquiz-d9ee2.appspot.com/o/animations%2Fthe-score%2Fbanana.gif?alt=media&token=5c44b0b4-7238-40a3-8ab5-42889781bf60" null:`,
        `-fill '#000000' -font "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/blizquiz-d9ee2.appspot.com/o/animations%2Fthe-score%2FChalkboardSE.ttf?alt=media&token=d83eadaf-9b81-4290-aa12-be6492f0243b" -pointsize 60 -annotate +270+530 '26%'`,
        `-layers composite -layers Optimize INLINE:GIF:-`,
      ],
      {capture: ['stdout', 'stderr']},
    );
```

The Error Log which I am getting:

```
stderr: convert-im6.q16: unable to open image `"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/blizquiz-d9ee2.appspot.com/o/animations%2Fthe-score%2Fbanana.gif?alt=media&token=5c44b0b4-7238-40a3-8ab5-42889781bf60" null:': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert-im6.q16: no decode delegate for this image format `GIF?ALT=MEDIA&TOKEN=5C44B0B4-7238-40A3-8AB5-42889781BF60" NULL:' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
convert-im6.q16: unrecognized option `-fill '#000000' -font "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/blizquiz-d9ee2.appspot.com/o/animations%2Fthe-score%2FChalkboardSE.ttf?alt=media&token=d83eadaf-9b81-4290-aa12-be6492f0243b" -pointsize 60 -annotate +270+530 '26%'' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/1673.
```

**Update**
Based on the feedback I got, I modified the code

```
var spawnPromise = spawn(
      'convert',
      [
        `"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/blizquiz-d9ee2.appspot.com/o/animations%2Fthe-score%2Fbanana.gif?alt=media&token=5c44b0b4-7238-40a3-8ab5-42889781bf60"`,
        `-fill`,
        `#000000`,
        `-font`,
        `"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/blizquiz-d9ee2.appspot.com/o/animations%2Fthe-score%2FChalkboardSE.ttf?alt=media&token=d83eadaf-9b81-4290-aa12-be6492f0243b"`,
        `-pointsize`,
        `60`,
        `-annotate`,
        `+270+530`,
        `26%`,
        `-layers`,
        `composite`,
        `-layers`,
        `optimize`,
        `INLINE:GIF:-`,
      ],
      {capture: ['stdout', 'stderr']},
    );
```

But still getting below the same error, although it works fine when executed locally.

```
stderr: convert-im6.q16: unable to open image `"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/blizquiz-d9ee2.appspot.com/o/animations%2Fthe-score%2Fbanana.gif?alt=media&token=5c44b0b4-7238-40a3-8ab5-42889781bf60"': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert-im6.q16: no decode delegate for this image format `GIF?ALT=MEDIA&TOKEN=5C44B0B4-7238-40A3-8AB5-42889781BF60"' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
convert-im6.q16: no images defined `INLINE:GIF:-' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.
```

Not able to figure out where I am wrong. The same command works perfectly on the local system when using ImageMagick. I would be grateful if anyone can point me in the right direction.
Thanks!

Comment: Is your **ImageMagick** `policy.xml` file preventing you from reading images from URLs?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Well I am using it in Firebase Cloud Functions, I am not aware whether it can be done in firebase, but definitely I am able to run this on my machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the command line and error message very carefully.  This is what you're passing as a URL:

> https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/blizquiz-d9ee2.appspot.com/o/animations%2Fthe-score%2Fbanana.gif?alt=media&token=5c44b0b4-7238-40a3-8ab5-42889781bf60" null:

Note the "null:" at the end.  That's not likely part of your URL.  It turns out, I think the way you are passing command parameters is also not correct.  Typically you pass each argument separately in the array that you pass to `spawn`.  This means you should probably separate out each flag and the value of each flag as separate array elements.  It should be more like how you see in the [documentation for spawn](http://Note%20the%20%22null:%22%20at%20the%20end.%20%20That's%20not%20likely%20part%20of%20your%20URL.%20%20It%20turns%20out,%20I%20think%20the%20way%20you%20are%20passing%20command%20parameters%20is%20not%20correct%20for).

Comment: Dear Doug, thanks for your support. I tried your suggestion but it looks like it's giving back the same error.

Comment: Kindly check the updated question and let me know if I doing anything wrong again.